# Having two different response types through the same route from a GET request

Tags: routes, spark-java

I'm using spark Java, and I've set the following route *localhost:4567//routeexemple/users/* for a GET request,
When I enter the parameter *testnight*   **(http://localhost:4567/routeexemple/users/?userName=testnight**) I have a value returned from the database as I expect , but when I enter the following query parameter *testApresmidi* (**http://localhost:4567/routeexemple/users/?userName=testApresmidi**)it says `The requested route [/routeexemple/users/] has not been mapped in Spark`.
What can be my mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It comes out that the version(2.0.0)  of spark I'm using is having a bug, they might have fixed it in the newer versions. The point is when I was trying to retrieve a nonexisting object from the db, rather than sending a NullPointerException, is was having the error message mentioned above. I hope they have fixed it on the newer versions.